# java close scanner & out of bounds exeption

Tags: java

i got two different kind of errors in my code.

one is when someone enters a number that's higher than 8 or lower than 0.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 22
    at boter_kaas_en_eiren.Board.placeAttempt(Board.java:37)
    at boter_kaas_en_eiren.Game.play(Game.java:28)
    at boter_kaas_en_eiren.MainClass.main(MainClass.java:12)
```

the other error is when a player wins and i want to close the scanner so nobody can play anymore.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Scanner closed
    at java.util.Scanner.ensureOpen(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.Scanner.findWithinHorizon(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.Scanner.nextLine(Unknown Source)
    at boter_kaas_en_eiren.Game.play(Game.java:23)
    at boter_kaas_en_eiren.MainClass.main(MainClass.java:12)
```

if somebody could help me i would appriciate it.

game class

```
package boter_kaas_en_eiren;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Game {

    private Board board;
    private boolean gameFinished;

    public Game() {
        board = new Board();
        gameFinished = false;
    }

    public void play() {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        int x = 0;
        String nextSymbol = "x";

        board.ShowBoard();

        while (gameFinished == false) {
            String input = scan.nextLine();
            int position = Integer.parseInt(input);

            boolean highorlow = board.tohighorlow(position);

            boolean succes = board.placeAttempt(position, nextSymbol);

            if (highorlow) {
                if (succes) {
                    if (nextSymbol.equals("x")) {
                        nextSymbol = "o";

                    } else {
                        nextSymbol = "x";
                    }

                }
            }

            board.ShowBoard();

            if (board.checkWinner("x") == true) {
                System.out.println("x wins");
                scan.close();
            }
            if (board.checkWinner("o") == true) {
                System.out.println("x wins");
                scan.close();
            }

        }

    }

}
```

main class

```
package boter_kaas_en_eiren;

public class MainClass {

    public static void main(String[] args) {


        Game game = new Game();



        game.play();
    }

}
```

board class

```
package boter_kaas_en_eiren;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Board {

    private String[] board;

    public Board() {
        board = new String[9];

        for (int i = 0; i < board.length; i++) {
            board[i] = " ";
        }

    }

    public void ShowBoard() {

        System.out.println(board[0] + "|" + board[1] + "|" + board[2]);
        System.out.println(board[3] + "|" + board[4] + "|" + board[5]);
        System.out.println(board[6] + "|" + board[7] + "|" + board[8]);
        System.out.println("");

    }

    public boolean tohighorlow(int position) {
        if (position <= 8 && position >= 0) {
            return true;
        } else {
            System.out.println("Invalid!!");
            return false;
        }
    }

    public boolean placeAttempt(int position, String symbol) {
        if (board[position].equals(" ")) {
            board[position] = symbol;
            return true;
        } else {
            System.out.println("invalid!");
            return false;
        }

    }

    public boolean checkWinner(String symbol) {
        if (board[0].equals(symbol) && board[1].equals(symbol) && board[2].equals(symbol)) {
            return true;
        } else if (board[3].equals(symbol) && board[4].equals(symbol) && board[5].equals(symbol)) {
            return true;
        } else if (board[6].equals(symbol) && board[7].equals(symbol) && board[8].equals(symbol)) {
            return true;
        } else if (board[0].equals(symbol) && board[3].equals(symbol) && board[6].equals(symbol)) {
            return true;
        } else if (board[1].equals(symbol) && board[4].equals(symbol) && board[7].equals(symbol)) {
            return true;
        } else if (board[2].equals(symbol) && board[5].equals(symbol) && board[8].equals(symbol)) {
            return true;
        } else if (board[0].equals(symbol) && board[4].equals(symbol) && board[8].equals(symbol)) {
            return true;
        } else if (board[2].equals(symbol) && board[4].equals(symbol) && board[6].equals(symbol)) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: First thing that I noticed: `if (position <= 8 && position >= 0)` should be `if (position <= 8 || position >= 0)`.

Comment: Which line is where?

Comment: And the second thing: you call `tohighorlow()` and follow with a call to `placeAttempt()`, regardless of the result of the first. You should not call `placeAttempt()` at all if `tohighorlow()` returned `true`.

Comment: @TRIX07 you might want to give some feedback, choose one answer as accepted and so on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you would thoroughly check the source code lines given in the exceptions, you could probably find the issues yourself. But let's go through it together this time:

**ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException**

This means you are trying to access an array element that is simply not there.
In your `Game` class, you have these two lines:

```
boolean highorlow = board.tohighorlow(position);
boolean succes = board.placeAttempt(position, nextSymbol);
```

Looking at `tohighorlow()`, we find this line:

```
if (position <= 8 && position >= 0) {
    return true;
}
```

However, this will return true if the number is in the range [0..8]. In other words, the method returns `true` when your number is **neither too high nor too low**. Easiest fix is to change the condition like this:

```
if (position > 8 || position < 0)
```

Now numbers greater than 8 or lower than 0 will yield `true`, which seems to be what the method is supposed to do. Alternatively, you could swap the bodies of the `if` and `else`.

Regardless of that, you are ignoring the result of this method when you call `placeAttempt()` in your `Game` class. That's not good, because looking at `placeAttempt()` we find this line:

```
 if (board[position].equals(" ")) { /* ... */
```

This is where your exception originates. You are accessing the `board` array without checking the `position` value. Or rather, you did check the `position` value but did not respect the result of that check here. Hence, if `position` is `-2` or `12`, for example, you will run into trouble as those elements do not exist (are out of bounds).

**IllegalStateException: Scanner closed**

Let's simplify the `play()` method of your `Game` class for a second:

```
public void play() {
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    /* ... */

    while (gameFinished == false) {
        String input = scan.nextLine();
        /* ... */

        boolean highorlow = board.tohighorlow(position);
        boolean succes = board.placeAttempt(position, nextSymbol);
        /* ... */

        if (board.checkWinner("x") == true) {
            System.out.println("x wins");
            scan.close();
        }
        if (board.checkWinner("o") == true) {
            System.out.println("x wins");
            scan.close();
        }
    }
}
```

The first thing you do is to create the `Scanner`. Now, under certain circumstances (the two `if` at the end), you close the scanner. However, you do that within a loop. After you close the scanner, the loops starts over with its first line:

```
String input = scan.nextLine();
```

But you can't get the next line of a closed scanner.

**Additional notes**

I noticed that you are quite inconsistent in your style. For example, see these three method names: `ShowBoard`, `placeAttempt` and `tohighorlow`. You use different capitalization for each. I strongly suggest to stick to the [recommended naming convention](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Naming_convention_(programming)#Java), which means camelCase with lower first letter: `showBoard`, `placeAttempt` and `tooHighOrLow` (also notice `to` vs `too`).

Hope this helps.

Comment: thank you for the help and the advice it helped me quited a bit :)

Comment: @TRIX07 Awesome! I hope you managed to get your code to work.

Answer (score 0):

Your array board has the size 9. So if someone enters a number not between 0 and 8 you get an Exception. 
You pass the input from the user directly to your function:

```
board.placeAttempt(position, nextSymbol);
```

There you do:

```
 if (board[position].equals(" ")) {
```

So you try to access an invalid position of the array